# How to apply brewer.pal to a list of values

Tags: r

is there any way to apply different colors for the list of strings?
It works for the list of integers, but not for strings

```
list1 <- c(1,2,3,3,4,4,5)
list2 <- c("1","2","3","4","4","5")
brewer.pal(9,'Set1')[list1]
[1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00"
brewer.pal(9,'Set1')[list2]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `match` and `unique` for string values.

```
brewer.pal(9,'Set1')[match(list2, unique(list2))]
#[1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00"
```

Or use `factor` -

```
brewer.pal(9,'Set1')[factor(list2)]
```

Comment: thank you! it works